# Getting error related to django model arrayfield

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djongo

When trying to access serialized.data, throws error for type models.ArrayField, but is successfully stored in mongodb.

models.py

```
 class testStep(models.Model):
    number      = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=100)
    payload     = models.JSONField(blank=True)
    header      = models.JSONField(blank=False)
    assertors   = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=assertStep, blank=True)
    
 class Meta:
        abstract = True

 class test(models.Model):
        _id   = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
        appId = models.ForeignKey(application, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        name  = models.TextField(blank=False, unique=True)
        step  = models.ArrayField(model_container=step, blank=True, default=list)
```

serializers.py

```
 class testStepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
            model            = models.testCase
            fields           = '__all__'
            read_only_fields = ['dateCreated', 'dateUpdated', ]
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            instance.testStep    = validated_data.get('testStep', instance.testStep)
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

views.py

```
    def put(self, request, testCaseId, format=None):
            tcDetails         = self.getTcDetails(testCaseId)
            reqData           = request.data.copy()
            if serialized.is_valid():
                     serialized.save()
                     return Response(json.loads(json_util.dumps(serialized.data)), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

trace back:

```
 line 355, in value_to_string
     post_dict = self._obj_thru_fields('value_to_string', container_obj)
     File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py",
 line 177, in _obj_thru_fields
     processed_value[field.attname] = getattr(field, func_name)(obj, *other_args)
     File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py",
 line 201, in value_to_string
     raise TypeError(f'Type: {type(value)} cannot be serialized')
     TypeError: Type: <class 'NoneType'> cannot be serialized
```

**update**
when i comment out
"assertors   = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=assertStep, blank=True)"
i am not seeing this error. Why is this causing error?

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: im not able to save full trace back..

Comment: Is that djongo, with an "o", in the traceback?

Comment: djongo is a module for integrating django with mongoDb (https://www.djongomapper.com/)